# How to remap a key to several characters in AutoHotKey?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, autohotkey

I'm making a keyboard layout where nearly every key maps to several characters. I know the usual syntax for remapping a key to a single other key is `a::b`, but that doesn't seem to work for multiple letters on the right hand side (e.g. `j::the`), and separating with spaces or commas doesn't work. Then I tried using `Send the` but that seems to result in excessive recursion as AHK tells me that it detects a bunch of keystrokes in the past milliseconds when I press a key). How do I assign a key to multiple characters?

I also tried hotstrings with the syntax `::j::the` but that seems to only activate when I press space after typing.

Comment: See [hotstrings-Options](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options)

Comment: @user3419297 Yeah I looked at it again and I think I know how to fix it. I'll post what I did soon.

Answer (score 1):

Hotstrings can indicate options, with the syntax `:options:hotkey::string`. An asterisk can be used to set the hotstring trigger to nothing (normally it's space). So for the `j` key to output `the`, type `:*:j::the`.